# Bitmap Splitting in android

Tags: android, bitmap

I have a question on Bitmap.

Requirement is to split the bitmap. I'm trying to split the bitmap using below code. First part is creating properly, but second part is also creating as same as first part.

**CODE:**

```
int start=0,end=500;
for(int i=0;i<2;i++) {
  try {
    Bitmap bm1 = Bitmap.createBitmap(originalBitmap, 0, start, originalBitmap.getWidth(), end);
    bitmaps.add(bm1);
  }
  catch (OutOfMemoryError e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
  start=end;
}
```

Is there any alternative solution for this?

anyone have idea please help me..

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

You are passing same values to create both bitmaps.... Give different values for height and width params as per your need. Check [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#createBitmap(android.graphics.Bitmap,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int))

For example

```
 for first bitmap
Bitmap one =  Bitmap.createBitmap(picture, 0, 0, picture.getWidth()/2 , picture.getHeight()/2);

//second bitmap
    Bitmap two = Bitmap.createBitmap(picture,0, picture.getHeight()/2, picture.getWidth()/2,picture.getHeight()/2);
```

Comment: thanks for reply... i'm changing the values in for loop. for first bitmap start=0,end=500 and for second one start = 500,end=500

Comment: why r u using for loop then ??

Comment: here i just given 2(for example) in for loop but i need to create more bitmaps based on height..

Comment: ohk... if this ans helps you then please accept it or upvote :)